# Card drawing question: expectation of how many turns to draw a 1 and a 5 from a deck of cards (replacing them each time)?

Tags: probability

Could someone please explain the theory behind this as best as possible please.

To elaborate on the question, what is the expected number of draws from a deck of cards so that you have both a 1 and a 5 - assuming cards are replaced and the same deck is used?

Comment: How long until the first time you see either a $1$ *or* a $5$?  Now that you have seen whichever it was... how long from then until you see the other?  $\frac{13}{2}+13$.  See more at [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).

Comment: What sort of deck are you playing with? [Standard $52$-card decks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_52-card_deck) don't have $1$s.

Comment: @joriki Aces are treated as 1's in several games.